# Switch Statements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am trying to run a switch statement that will look to see if the option of a credit card has been chosen and add 2% to the total cost, the code bellow is what i have created

```
        if (payment.value){
      switch (payment.value) {
          case 'Credit Card'
            cost = cost + (cost * 0.2);
            break;
          case 'Gold Bullion'
            cost = cost + (cost * 0.5);
            break;
          default: cost;
      }

<label for="type">Payment Method</label> <select name="payment" id="payment" required>
      <option value="DC">Debit Card</option>
      <option value="CC">Credit Card</option>
      <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
      <option value="GB">Gold Bullion</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: i have decleared the var at the top by using var payment = document.getElementById('payment');

Comment: You're missing two colons.

Comment: where is `cost` declared? also, `default` isn't needed...

Comment: `cost + (cost * 0.2)` is a 20% increase. For 2% you want `0.02`.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the ":" in the case statements.

```
switch (payment.value) {
      case 'Credit Card':
        cost = cost + (cost * 0.2);
        break;
      case 'Gold Bullion':
        cost = cost + (cost * 0.5);
        break;
      default: cost;
  }
```

Comment: `payment.value` is either DC, CC, Cash, or GB. Not 'Credit Card', etc., that is the `text` of the option

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing you colons for Credit Card and Gold Bullion.

`switch (payment.value) {
     case 'Credit Card':
          cost = cost + (cost * 0.2);
          break;
     case 'Gold Bullion':
          cost = cost + (cost * 0.5);
          break;
         default: cost;
     }`

Comment: Looks like you are missing lots of things too!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var payment = document.getElementById('payment');
if (payment.value) {
  switch (payment.value) {
      case 'CC':
        cost *= 1.02;
        break;
      case 'GB':
        cost *= 1.5;
        break;
      // Etc. you can use more cases of course.
}
```

Look at the cases, it uses the `value`property of the option, not the text you put in between the `option` tags.

```
<label>Payment Method
   <select name="payment" id="payment" required>
      <option value="DC">Debit Card</option>
      <option value="CC">Credit Card</option>
      <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
      <option value="GB">Gold Bullion</option>
   </select>
</label>
```

Comment: `default` is not needed!

Answer (score -1):

If you set a `value` attribute on an option, that will be the value of the `<select>` when that option is selected, *not* the text inside the option element. So in this case, "DC", "CC", etc.

And gmast is correct about your syntax error, too.